# How do I ensure that using `gcloud app deploy` is using my build folder not my dev files?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

I am new to google app engine. I have a react app

Before deploying to production I use `npm run build` which creates / updated the build folder.  Then I push my app to app engine using `gcloud app deploy`.

How do I know that the server is using the files in my build folder?

Is there something I should specify in my app.yaml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an NPM script to first change into the desired `build` directory when deploying the App Engine app.

### package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "app.deploy": "cd dist/app/ && gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project api-project-########## --version v2 --no-promote --verbosity debug"
   ...
}
```

Run the script:

```sh
npm run app.deploy
```

Comment: Btw, for anyone else, this link helped me determine what some of those flags do: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: Do I even need to run `npm run build`? or is google app engine making a production minimized version for me when I run `gcloud app deploy`?

Comment: @r-dev You still need to run `build` to create the minimized React app.

Comment: thank you.  Can I follow up with one more question please?  Since my app.yaml is in my build directory now. Do I also manually include a package.json file in my build directory so that GAE can find a start script?

Comment: @r-dev GAE doesn't use `package.json`. Once `app.yaml` and the application files are in the correct structure within the `build` directory, you are good to go.